# 研究会の会長でいらっしゃいます。 and お元気でいらっしゃるそうです

Tags: honorifics

> 研究会の会長でいらっしゃいます。

> お元気でいらっしゃるそうです。

I know the above is described as 尊敬語 (目上の人の行為を言う) Respectful Language for だ. Used to refer to the actions of supervisors.

Can someone explain when or in what situation this will be used? Is this an action of the supervisor? It seems like just a statement: "The chairman of this research group is this person"

Who would say this, the chairman themselves or someone underneath this chairman from another group / clan?

Also for 2 the same questions as above.
would it be someone underneath the guy from another clan saying:
"From what I heard, That person seems fine?"

Answer (score 1):

As you said, いらっしゃる is an honorific version of だ. Simply, there is even an honorific version of "is" in Japanese. It's used to describe the state of "being" of someone respectfully.

In general, **anyone** who needs to pay respect to that chairman will use the honorific language. They may or may not belong to the same organization, and they may or may not be directly beneath the chairman. Sometimes it's used by someone who is *above* the mentioned person. For example, in a wedding speech, a president may use the honorific language when introducing a bride who is their subordinate. On the other hand, 尊敬語 is not used in news or Wikipedia articles where objective writing style is preferred.